# Show only icon in floating action button

Tags: android, floating-action-button, material-components, material-components-android

I want to show only my drawable icon in FloatingActionButton (for min 14 API level and higher). I tried with src, background, changed background tint, borderWidth, all kinds of things but nothing helped. Even changing size of my drawable doesn't change its size in display. It is small and surrounded by button background. I want it to be bigger and without background.

PS. don't want to do it with ImageView and lose all functionalities that FloatingActionButton offer.

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_circle"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Have you tried putting 'android:background="#0000"' or 'app:backgroundTint="@null"'?

Comment: didn't help, solution is below

Comment: Maybe it's gotten easier to do this, but I've used stringbuilder to add an icon to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/faBtn"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"


    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_circle"

    app:fabCustomSize="@dimen/fabSize"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:maxImageSize="@dimen/fabImageSize"

    android:background="@null"
    android:backgroundTint="@null"

    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:elevation="0dp"
/>
```

For the fab to not cast a shadow you need to have an elevation of 0; didn't find any other way.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like:

```
  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
      android:id="@+id/fab_test"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"

      app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_search_24"
      app:tint="@color/selector_button"
      app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
      app:elevation="0dp"
      app:maxImageSize="@dimen/design_fab_size_mini"
      app:pressedTranslationZ="0dp"
      ../>
```

- `app:srcCompat` to add the icon (instead of `android:src`)
- `app:backgroundTint` define a transparent color for your background
- `app:elevation="0dp"` remove the elavation
- `app:pressedTranslationZ="0dp"` remove the TranslationZ for the FAB when pressed
- `app:maxImageSize` define the max size of the icon. You can use a custom value or standard values as `design_fab_size_mini` = `40dp` or `design_fab_size_normal`= `56dp`
- `app:tint`: define the color of your icon. You can use a selector to handle the pressed state.

Something like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="@color/mycolor" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
  <item android:color="@color/myPrimaryColor" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

Normal and pressed state result:

[image]
[image]

Comment: yes but when I add elevation 0dp, i can not perform click on floatingButton...?

Comment: It works (I am using the version 1.1.0). The elevation doesn't change the `onClickListener`. If you don't have a selector defined in the `app:tint` (as in the answer), the user doesn't have an evidence on the button.